# lightning:datatable Show alert for deselected row

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

I need to show an alert whenever a row is deselected in lightning data table. Can someone help me achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `onrowselection` event handler implemented in the component reference example [Datatable with selectable rows](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleDatatableBase) for `lightning:datatable`. If you need a specific issue resolved, I suggest you to cite more details in the question about what you have tried already.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont need some thing to happen on row selection. I need something like onRowDeselection which I know is not directly available.

Comment: `rowselection` event is fired both when you select or **deselect** the checkbox on a row of `lightning:datatable`.  Hence, the question about what specific problem are you trying to solve?